AC Freezing after replacing burnt 5 Amp fuse in AC Control Board
Years ago our thermostat wire outside was cut and all wires had to be spliced with nuts. Recently my outdoor fan wasn’t kicking on and the house was getting warm. In troubleshooting, I wiggled the splice and the fan instantly kicked on and the house was cooling just as normal. Months later I came to find no power on my thermostat. Troubleshooting and online research led me to check the control board in the handler where I found the 5 amp fuse blown. Since I changed the fuse, the ac works as normal for hours before I notice it freezing over. I’ve changed the filter, checked fins, but none of this was an issue before the fuse blew. I am going to unsplice and re-splice the breaks in the thermostat wire since that is likely causing some problems but what might be causing the freezing given thins information? Is a possible broken connection in the slice not signaling something to function properly? Thanks for your insights!
Update - I turned off the Cooling function and turned on the fan to try to defrost the unit. 30 min later I felt cold air coming through the vents like the system was running normally. I double checked the thermostat and the cooling was still off. I went to the outdoor unit and the fan and compressor were running. I gather that a fault is either causing the outdoor unit to continue running when the inside unit stops or a fault is turning on the outdoor unit at random. When I touched the thermostat splice the outdoor unit instantly cut off.

freezing is usually caused by low coolant level

The dead fuse is more likely to be a symptom than a cause, unless you damaged the system while replacing the fuse.

what kind of nuts did you use to splice the thermostat wire with?
